# Solve Resistance per unit in simple problem

Tags: amperage, basic-stamp, ohms

I'm just learning basic electronic. I don't understand this simple problem.

A 400 ohm resistor carries a current of 60 Ampers.

resistance is R per unit (pu) = 400ohm/32ohm = 12.5

how can I obtain this 32 ohm? I have no idea where it come from.

EDIT: This is a resolved problem with resolved exercices, the thing is that I don't understand how to get some values, the process I mean.

Comment: We have no idea either, as your question doesn't mention it.

Comment: So, is that 32 Ohms per meter, perhaps? So you have a 400 Ohm resistor with a length of 400/32 = 12.5 meters? You really should elaborate more.

Answer (score 1):

per unit designation is a power systems engineering principal that allows for easy transformation/scaling.

In this case, the resistance is scaled against a base resistance of 32 \$\Omega\$ which would be defined from  \$\dfrac{base volts}{base amps}\$

Comment: I don't understand. Could you be more precise? You mean that the default resistence is 32 Ω?

Comment: @MarcoGarzini here is something from Wikipedia that I found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per-unit_system